# How can I enable Tab completion to minikube?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, minikube, tab-completion

I'm trying to enable tab-completion to minikube on ubuntu 16.04.
There is some way to do so?

Answer (score 7):

To enable `minikube` autocomplete you can use below  script can be used.
Please pay attention that `bash-completion` package should be installed in your system

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
# minikube (Local Kubernetes) completion

if command -v minikube &>/dev/null
then
  eval "$(minikube completion bash)"
fi
```

Putting below part to  ~/.bashrc also will do its job

```
if command -v minikube &>/dev/null
then
  eval "$(minikube completion bash)"
fi
```

And there is also one more way you can achieve the same: create `minikube` completion file under `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d` directory:

```
$ minikube completion bash > /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/minikube-completion
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: BTW, the same methods can be used to enable autocomplete for the `kubectl` CLI

Answer (score 2):

From [official site](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/completion), we can find the suggestions.

Ubuntu:

```
Ubuntu:
    $ apt-get install bash-completion
    $ source /etc/bash-completion
    $ source <(minikube completion bash) # for bash users
    $ source <(minikube completion zsh) # for zsh users
    $ minikube completion fish > ~/.config/fish/completions/minikube.fish # for fish users

Additionally, you may want to output the completion to a file and source in your .bashrc

Note for zsh users: [1] zsh completions are only supported in versions of zsh >= 5.2
Note for fish users: [2] please refer to this docs for more details https://fishshell.com/docs/current/#tab-completion
```